# Can I change the name of my site as shown in the mobile search results on Google?

Tags: google-search, wordpress, search-results, mobile, breadcrumbs

I'm working on a wp site that is displaying the incorrect name of the brand for Google search results. This only happens on a phone/mobile. Each search result is in a card with a little breadcrumb result at the top. The title displays normally, but it's the breadcrumb title/url trail title that is wrong. The title should read as one word (EarlyBird), not two.  Is this something I can fix, or does Google generate this somehow?

[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the search results where it shows the incorrect info?

Comment: I've updated my post with an image to help clarify what I mean.

Comment: I deleted my answer as I had not understood it. I believe the source of this data is likely in WordPress somewhere. Are you using Yeost or SEO Press or similar?

Comment: I'm using Yoast, but I feel like I've looked everywhere in there and couldn't find any instances of it.